# how to implement Rate Us in android

Tags: android

I have made an application now i want to implement Rate Us feature in it. so for that i have added this code in my app

```
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.bet.compny"));
startActivity(i);
break;
```

but when i click on the button for rate us getting force close. here is my log cat output.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {     
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.bet.compny }
```

Any help would be appretiated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Idk why you get the Error, but this should actually work. I also do it like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
```

But keep in mind that this would crash, if you are testing it on an Emulator/ a device without a play store. So I would suggest you to wrap it in a try and catch

Comment: one parenthesis is missing at the end which is )

Answer (score 18):

This error occurs when running on a device without the **Google PlayStore**. 
I guess you might be running this on a emulator device which doesn't have Playstore and hence the error.

Implement using try catch as follows:

```
try{
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+getPackageName())));
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName())));
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I am always using below code which is useful for us:

```
Intent rateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName())); 
startActivity(rateIntent);
```

In think it will help full for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way to do it;

> Appirater is an android library based off the original Appirater By
>   Arash Payan Appirater iPhone. The goal is to create a cleanly designed
>   App Rating prompt that you can drop into any android app that will
>   help remind your users to review your app on the android Market.

https://github.com/sbstrm/appirater-android

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
    startActivity(marketIntent);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
    startActivity(marketIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Best and Simple Code**

```
private final String mStoreLink;
```

*Without Activity need context/activity*

```
 this.mStoreLink = "market://details?id=" + activity.getPackageName();
```

*Creat a method like this.*

```
public void rateUsOnGooglePlay() {
        final Uri marketUri = Uri.parse(mStoreLink);
        try {
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Couldn't find PlayStore on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This commonly happens on a device without the Google Play Store

Answer (score 0):

i think u have test this code in emulator, and emulator have no plastore application, so this error came.

I have implement this and my code is like this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=applicationID of play sotre")));
```

please put try catch in bellow code.

and try this code in android device.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I wanted the user to click on "MORE BY US" and he would be redirected
to my playstore homepage, but the app was crashing. The reason was simple. I added extra spaces and lines to the link something like below:

```
<string name = "more_app_link">

   playstore.link...............

</string>
```

then I removed extra lines and spaces like this:

```
<string name = "more_app_link">playstore.link...............</string>
```

and it worked very well.